# Unique IP Counter with Laravel and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to make a simple Unique IP counter for gallery page views.

The idea I have is to keep the views records separate from the image records in 2 tables.

### Database Tables

#### gallery

Holds Image: `id`, `name`, `category`, `views` columns

[image: gallery]

#### unique_ips

Holds a visitor `ip` for the Image `name` viewed

This example screenshot shows 3 visitors each viewing 3 images. I used free proxy ips.

[image: unique_ips]

### View Counter

If New IP detected:

Add `name`+`ip` to `unique_ips`.
Increment `gallery` → `name` → `views` +1.

```
$name = "Image 1";
$ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');

// Increment Views if New IP visitor
// Proceed if name + ip record does not exist in table
if (!DB::table('unique_ips')->where('name', '=', $name)->where('ip', '=', $ip)->exists()) { 

    // Add Name/IP Record
    DB::table('unique_ips')->insert([
        ['name' => $name, 'ip' => $ip]
    ]);

    // Views +1 
    DB::table('gallery')
        ->where('name', $name)
        ->increment('views', 1);
}
```

### Problem

This view counter works, but all unique ip records are grouped together under 2 columns. It would have to search through *all* records to find a match, which might slow down with thousands of ip's.

**Other Ideas**

1. Use only the `gallery` table and add a
   `unique_ips` column, which would hold an array of ip's. But how many
   could it hold if string/text is limited to a number of characters?
2. Each `name` could have it's own Column containing ip's. But then I'd have thousands of Columns.
3. I could store ip's in `name` text files instead of in the database.

Is there a better way to design this?

Comment: ipv4 exists of 4 octets that can be translated to 1 digit. pretty easy selecting from that on. However, that will become difficult on ipv6.

Comment: IP'S really dont mean anything, what do you hope to achieve?

Comment: @nogad 1 view increment per IP. I also made a session counter, but closing and reopening the browser could add multiple views.

Comment: IP  != person, so what's the point

Comment: @nogad How would you count unique views?

Comment: i guess you have to define "unique" here, because hundreds can share one IP. i would trust in google analytics myself

Comment: @nogad It's for displaying a view counter on the page. It doesn't have to be 100% accurate, but close to 1 view per network ip or computer. I'm also looking into session + cookie counter, but if cookies are disabled it would count every page refresh.

Comment: Redis visits counter for Eloquent models alsoe it has ip protection . I hope this what you looking for https://github.com/if4lcon/Bareq

Answer (score 1):

At first it would be faster to use *gallery_id* instead of *name* with relationship.

And if you don't want to slow down process on clients side, you can make queued event-listener, that will handle checking and adding record to database.

Check out following link about [Queued event listeners](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/events#queued-event-listeners)